# R: How to create a function from a model?

Tags: r, stepwise-regression

I am using an automatic model selection procedure, "step". The model of depart (the biggest possible) is a polynom, say of the 4th degree.

```
Depart<-lm(y~x+I(x^2)+I(x^3)+I(x^4))

Final<-step(Depart)
```

I need to transform the Final model to a corresponding function. How can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

`f<-function(newdata)predict(Final,data.frame(x=newdata))`

?

Comment: No, i wish to construct a function of one variable. Something like "ff<-function(x) 3.23+2.78x-3.45x^4".

Comment: @Roah Did you try the answer? Because that's exactly what it will give you (you won't see the coefficients, but why do you care about the internals of the function?

Comment: @Roah - Could you explain in what way the function I suggested does not do what you expect? It certainly accepts scalars so you can call it with a single value. Is the return value not what you are expecting?

Comment: Sorry, aix! I was too bothered by the internal structure of the algorithm... And it is very simple! Thanks a lot, because i was going to parse the output...